# XQuery modify with variable

Tags: t-sql, xquery

I have the follow XML

```
<root>
   <business name="LM" id="1" total_pes="0">
   </business>
   <business name="KO" id="354" total_pes="0">
   </business>
   <business name="TUI" id="889" total_pes="0">
   </business>
</root>
```

I want to update the total_pes attribute with a record count of other table tbl_logs:

```
id   |   log
1    |    A
1    |    A
1    |    A
354  |    A
354  |    A
889  |    A
```

My output XML would be this:

```
 <root>
   <business name="LM" id="1" total_pes="3">
   </business>
   <business name="KO" id="354" total_pes="2">
   </business>
   <business name="TUI" id="889" total_pes="1">
   </business>
</root>
```

This is what I already done:

```
DECLARE @total_pes_new int
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @IDS)

WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
set @total_pes_new = (  SELECT COUNT(A.PES) FROM TBL A
                        WHERE A.ID = @ID)
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/root/business[@id=sql:variable("@ID")]/@total_pes)[1] with sql:variable("@total_pes_new")')

SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @IDS WHERE ID > @ID)
END
```

I will have problems with this loop. Can anyone help me to do a better solution?

Tks

Comment: Why do you want to do this without a loop?

Comment: I'm sure there are enough people willing to help if you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your XML is in an XML database, then you also have the option of using XQuery Update, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/.